# Why subview always attaches to top in UIStackView?

Tags: ios, uistackview

I have three subviews(one UIImageView and two UILabels) in one horizontal UIStackView. I notice there is constraint which makes UIImageView attaches the top of the stack view.  How can I remove this and make all subviews's centerY pin to superView's centerY? Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? All view inside a stackview have a center aligment and given width constrain to UIImageview.

[image: CenterY all the subview of stackview]